# How to limit the jQuery focus to the current ajax form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to handle multiple forms on one page. All forms are within a `<div class="myclass">`.

Now on any error, I want to place a little error message after the form. The following code basically works, but it adds the error message after **each** form on the page.

```
$('.myclass form').ajaxForm({
    success: function(response) {
        // do something
    },
    error: function() {
        $('.myclass form').after("<div>error</div>");
        // adds the error message to ALL forms on the page
    }
});
```

How can I limit the focus to the current form I am using? Unfortunately `$(this)` does not return the current form I am using, but the whole jQuery object.

Comment: What defines the "current form you are using" ? The fact that you focus a specific input ?

Comment: What does "the whole jQuery object" mean? What does it contain?

Comment: It's usually the second parameter `error: function(formData, this_form) { ...`

Comment: @Juhana: As described, I have multiple forms on the page, each one in the `div.myclass`. I want to limit to the **one** form among all forms.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But if you do `$(this)` what do you get? You say it's a "whole jQuery object" but what's in that object?

Comment: When you use `$(this)` e.g. within `.click()`, you get the clicked element. In my case, `$(this)` contains the whole DOM tree of the page.

Comment: Why don't you just tell us what plugin you're using, there are at least five called `ajaxForm` ?

Comment: @adeneo: I linked it...

Comment: @adeneo The link for the plugin is part of the question.

Comment: And looking at the documentation it seems all the methods have the current form as the second parameter, as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @adeneo can you provide a link? I didn't find it. Is it the same for the success routine?

Comment: All the other methods follow that pattern, `event: function(formData, THIS_FORM, something) {...`, so just try it and see ?

Comment: I debugged it through, neither the `success` nor the `error` method have the current form as parameter. But I can fetch it from the `beforeSubmit` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to limit access to the current form:

```
var form = null;

$('.myclass form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function(data, dataForm) {
        form = dataForm;
    },
    success: function(response) {
        // form can also be accessed here
    },
    error: function() {
        form.after("<div>error</div>");
        // only append to current form
    }
});
```